# java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target in my lib

Tags: java, android, robolectric

I have a library in a private Maven repository. But when I passed it to one of my clients he reported me the following problem when running his tests with robolectric.

Whats does this problem means and how can I solve it?

Full stacktrace:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 45
Exception Details:
Location:
com/mylib/MyBroadcastReceiver.onReceive(Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/content/Intent;)V @37: ifeq
Reason:
Expected stackmap frame at this location.
Bytecode:
0x0000000: 1202 bb00 0b59 b700 1312 01b6 0014 2cb6
....

at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at org.robolectric.internal.Shadow.newInstanceOf(Shadow.java:22)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowApplication.registerBroadcastReceivers(ShadowApplication.java:138)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowApplication.bind(ShadowApplication.java:127)
at org.robolectric.shadows.CoreShadowsAdapter.bind(CoreShadowsAdapter.java:76)
at org.robolectric.internal.ParallelUniverse.setUpApplicationState(ParallelUniverse.java:115)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:329)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:259)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:41)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:199)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:119)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Comment: Does he have a different version of your library in test scope?

Comment: No, the library is the same version (using "compile" in gradle)

Comment: I'm guessing since all reference for this error is an bytecode mismatch - Does your library instantiate BroadcastReceiver? Is it compiled with JDK 6?

Comment: Tried with and without `sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7` in the library but it fails anyway =(

Comment: What about if you set `sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6` instead? It might work sans stackmaps if you set the compatibility version to JDK 6.